# how to add a logo to this wordpress code

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I downloaded this free WP Simple theme and is modifying mostly everything in the backend. Otherwise, I'll have to pay more and I heard from some people who said that they paid for this theme and didn't get all the features and support they wanted.

Anyway, I'm trying to add the logo to this code

```
<?php
$nimbus_image_logo = trim(nimbus_get_option('nimbus_image_logo'));
$nimbus_text_logo = trim(nimbus_get_option('nimbus_text_logo'));
if (empty($nimbus_image_logo)) {
    if (!empty($nimbus_text_logo)) {
    ?>
        <h1 class="text_logo"><a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>"><?php echo $nimbus_text_logo; ?></a></h1>
    <?php
    }
} else {
?>
    <a class="" href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>"><img class="image_logo" src="<?php echo $nimbus_image_logo; ?>" alt="<?php echo get_bloginfo('name', 'display'); ?>" /></a>
<?php
}
?>
```

The logo url is `"<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/Novalogo.png"`.

I tried adding it to $nimbus_image_logo = at top, but it's not working. I also tried to add and replace it at `<?php echo $nimbus_image_logo; ?>` but it's not working also.

How do I fix it?

Comment: I'd recommend making a child theme (https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) instead of editing directly the theme's templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a simple solution for an image only logo, replace everything with just this line.

```
<a class="" href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>"><img class="image_logo" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/Novalogo.png" alt="<?php echo get_bloginfo('name', 'display'); ?>" /></a>
```

Comment: Thanks! But you made a slight mistake in the code. the "" in the src should be wrapping around the url. I thought at first that it wasn't working and then looking over the code, found that mistake and now everything is working!!!

Comment: Many apologies. At the time I was posting from an xbox360.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess would be to remove the conditional statement entirely.
Try removing all of that code and just leaving this:

```
<a class="" href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>"><img class="image_logo" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/Novalogo.png" alt="<?php echo get_bloginfo('name', 'display'); ?>" /></a>
```